# Print lines until the second field changes

Tags: regex, shell, command-line, awk, sed

Let's say this is my command line output:

```
Mike    US  11
John    US  3
Dina    US  1002
Dan     US  44
Mike    UK  552
Luc     US  23
Jenny   US  23
```

I want to print all lines starting from first line and stop printing once the second field changes to something other than "US" even if there are more "US" after that. So I want to the output to be:

```
Mike    US  11
John    US  3
Dina    US  1002
Dan     US  44
```

This is the code I have right now:

```
awk '$2 == "US"{a=1}$2 != "US"{a=0}a'
```

It works fine as long as there are no more "US" after the range I matched. So my current code will output like this:

```
Mike    US  11
John    US  3
Dina    US  1002
Dan     US  44
Luc     US  23
Jenny   US  23
```

As you may notice, it dropped the "UK" line and kept printing which is not what I'm trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic approach, it prints to second filed change, regardless of data in second field

```
awk '$2!=f && NR>1 {exit} 1; {f=$2}' file
Mike    US  11
John    US  3
Dina    US  1002
Dan     US  44
```

This just test if its `US`, if not exit. Maybe more correct to your question:

```
awk '$2!="US" {exit}1' file
Mike    US  11
John    US  3
Dina    US  1002
Dan     US  44
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is something more elegant, but this does the job:

```
awk 'BEGIN { P=1 } P == 1 && $2 != "US" { P = 0 }P' filename
```

Comment: @Sameh works fine on your test data. Gives same output as I posted in my post.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/US/!Q' file
```

If the line does not contain `US` quit.

For specifically the second field:

```
sed '/^\S\+\s\+US\b/!Q' file
```